# What is Uri parameter in curl?

Tags: windows, docker, curl, https, uri

I am using this command on windows powershell to execute my docker image :
`curl -i https://localhost:49160`

which is further taking me to this prompt :
`cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: Uri:`

what is Uri ? and what to enter in this ?

I tried entering
`https://localhost:3030  (my server side port)  localhost:3030  http://localhost:49160  (my docker side port)`

and combinations of these..

it is resulting in this error :

`curl : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

`-i` in powershell curl does not mean the same as `-i` in standard curl. Curl in Powershell is simply an alias of `Invoke-Webrequest` and you got unlucky that `-i` actually means something to `Invoke-Webrequest`.

It doesn't mean 'insecure' like in standard curl. It means 'Infile' which is why it thinks that the next parameter is a filename. And then it asks for the URI to call, since it thinks you haven't specified it.

Try dropping the `-i` option. There's no equivalent option on `Invoke-Webrequest` to my knowledge. So your command should be

```
curl https://localhost:49160
```

Personally, I'd use

```
Invoke-Webrequest https://localhost:49160
```

since that makes it very clear that you're not actually using curl.

Alternatively, you can install a Windows version of actual curl and use that.